# select2 ajax shows results but can't select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 plugin with remote ajax data. I can see the results in the dropdown but can't select them. I want the results to be selectable and placed into the field after selection. I think the problem is with passing the id, I don't know how to pass it correctly.. Any ideas?

my json for ?tag_word=for ...there is no id

```
results: [{text: "fort"}, {text: "food"}]
```

Here the code:

```
    <select class="js-data-example-ajax" style="width:100%">
      <option selected="selected">asdasd</option>
    </select>

    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/select2.js' %}"></script>
    <script >
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    multiple:true,
    delay: 250,
    cache: true,
    ajax: {
      url: '/tags/search/autocomplete/',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function (parms, page) { return { tag_word: parms.term }; },
    },
  });
});  
    </script>
```

here is the server code:

```
def autocomplete(request):
s = SearchQuerySet(using='autocomplete')
sqs = s.autocomplete(content_auto=request.GET.get('tag_word'))[:5]
suggestions = [  {'text':result.tag_word,
                    'id':result.tag_word,} for result in sqs]
the_data = json.dumps({
    'results': suggestions
})
return HttpResponse(the_data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: you need to use the **success:** of $.ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a quick hack. Not sure how you could get along with select2 documentaion. But the following code worked with me in my localhost.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $.get("json/select.json",function(data){ //specify your url for json call inside the quotes.
             for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                 data[i]={id:i,text:data[i].text}
             }
            $(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
                    minimumInputLength: 2,
                    multiple:true,
                    delay: 250,
                    data: data   
            })

    });
}
```

Comment: If I use the above code I get the error: http://127.0.0.1:8000/tags/search/autocomplete/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: Ok i did it on the server side since I can't find out the solution on client side.. I just added same property 'tag_word' also for id and not only for text.. now is working

Comment: Pick the right answer so it will be helpful for other who search on the same base.

Answer (score 9):

To select an option each and every result need to have a unique id. Therefore you can add id using following code(`processResults`).

```
$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    multiple:true,
    delay: 250,
    cache: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/tags/search/autocomplete/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (parms, page) { return { tag_word: parms.term }; },
        processResults: function (data) {
                    data.results.forEach(function (entry, index) {
                        entry.id = ''+index; // Better if you can assign a unique value for every entry, something like UUID
                    });

                    return data;
                },
                cache: true
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because you got all id's null. change to numbers. Click on the get selected button to see the ids only will be passed.

```
var data = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    multiple:true,
    delay: 250,
    data: data


  });
});

$(".checkoutput").click(function(){
console.log($('.js-data-example-ajax').val());
})
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/2h2bwvc5/)

Comment: my id's are null that's the problem you are correct. Can you please explain how do I pass only id values to json? I tried your suggestion but can't make it work.

Comment: //how do I pass only id values to json// Couldnt get your point. You need to keep id and text. And you need to give unique value for each id.

Comment: yes i need both id and text but I already get the text.. I miss the id and I can't figure out how to give unique value to each id.. my current results: [{text: "fort"}, {text: "food"}].. there is no id. How do I add unique id to my results?

Comment: [{id:0, text: "fort"}, {id:1,text: "food"}]. Did i get your question?

Comment: yes this should be the final result but I load json with ajax.  My question is how to add id unique values when I use remote data loading and I don't have an array of values..

Comment: If you have not created the json, then you need to ask the backend guys to create the similar json for you. The quick way to test your front-end code is create a json file and call that file instead of url and check. If it works fine then you can ask  your backend guys to create similar json for you. Hope i was clear.

Comment: I have the backend and it's calling only tag_word which is a charfield. I could call also the pk and use that as id but I'm sure there are other ways to add id's dynamically in jquery. This link http://javascriptgraduate.com/question/select2-js-plugin-not-able-to-select-any-option/ has the exact same issue that I'm facing and I tried also his method but can't add the id to my results. As i said my backend json is created but returns only "text" not also the "id". That is the reason why i can see the results but can't select them...

Comment: you are using jquery or javascipt

Comment: for this case I'm using jquery select2 (loading remote data)

Comment: see this jsfiddle. look into the console. it will add id to your json value. http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/084wbz0g/

Comment: can you please show me exactly where should I insert your code?

Comment: @gibberish is right. you need to append the code after success function.

Answer (score 0):

Further to your final question on Alaksandar's answer, try adding his code like this:

```
$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    multiple:true,
    delay: 250,
    cache: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/tags/search/autocomplete/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (parms, page) { return { tag_word: parms.term }; },
        success: function(results){
            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                results[i] = {id:i,text:results[i].text}
            }
        }
    },
});
```

I haven't tested any of this. So, if it works, please accept Aleksandar's answer as correct, not this one.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions but I still can't select the items and the console is showing: results: [{text: "fort"}, {text: "food"}]...without id value

Comment: what is your parms.term output